# Pass ' " ' into a file using ECHO in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, echo

I want to have the following string in my file.

```
#define Test "c:drive\folder\test1.txt"
```

Here, I am basically taking the *.txt file (the name of the file is always changing) present in this folder.

I am using the following code:

```
DEL Listfile.txt
echo | set /p="#define Test "c:drive\folder\""> Listfile.txt
dir /B *.txt >> Listfile.txt
```

However, here the problem is that the file name `test1.txt` is coming after the `"` e.g.

```
#define Test "c:drive\folder\"test1.txt
```

I cannot find another way to end include the file name in between the `"`.

Comment: Are you trying to loop through all files in a folder via a batch file and then prepend the text `#define Test "c:\drive\folder\"` or are you trying to get the full path of the file, then output that to the file `ListFile.txt`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@echo off
DEL Listfile.txt
set char="
for /F "delims==" %%d in ('dir /B *.txt') DO ( 
    echo | Set /P="#define Test %char%c:drive\folder\%%d%char%">>Listfile.txt
    echo.>>Listfile.txt
)
```

Answer (score 0):

A mix of the answers of GOTO 0 and payeli.

```
del Listfile.txt
for /F "delims=" %%d in ('dir /B *.txt') DO (
     > Listfile.txt echo #define Test "c:drive\folder\%%d"
)
```

It's necessary to use a FOR /F loop here, as in the other case (solution of GOTO 0) it's possible that the FOR loop will find also the `Listfile.txt` after the first line is echoed.
The FOR /F will work, as it first reads the complete output of the dir command before the DO part is executed.

But now it's possible to use only one echo to output the complete line at once.

If `C:\drive\folder\` is also the absolute path of your text file you could change the echo line to:

```
> Listfile.txt echo  #define Test "%%~fd"
```

Comment: Don't you want `>>` instead of `>`?

Comment: First I also thought, but the output makes no sense when there is more than one line defining a macro named test